# Searching Redux vs Searching API

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, react-redux

I'm working a search function for an site. One of the requirements to create a simple search, where we're able to search one or more parameters.

The current iteration right now is using Redux to fetch everything from a database and then I am filtering down an array.

```
 private searchByAll = () => {
  const filteredArray : Array<Invoice> = this.props.invoices.filter((invoice : Invoice) => {
    return(
      invoice['invoiceNumber'].toString() === this.state.queryText ||
      invoice['vendor'].toString().toLowerCase() === this.state.queryText.toString().toLowerCase() ||
      invoice['purchaser'].toString().toLowerCase() === this.state.queryText.toString().toLowerCase()
    )
  })

  this.checkArray(filteredArray); 
}
```

I am questioning if this is the right way to do it or if I should set an API end point to search the database. I'm just not sure which is the most approriate way to handle this. As the application grows and there's 100's of records I feel like the API route might be best for performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the data in your local Redux store, that's what you want to search. However, if you have data that you are not always loading into the front end, you'll want to run that search on the server and return results to the front end.